# Selecting certain columns from table A and insert to table B

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Trying to select certain data columns from CART table and add it to ORDER table. I created an insert order method which will copy some columns from CART and add to ORDER table. But an error was thrown because I have a column in ORDER which is "product_stats". Instead of adding "product_stats" to CART, how to query in such a way that product_stats in ORDER will be neglected when copying certain columns from CART?
Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I am not very familiar with SQL queries.

**ORDER and CART table:**

```
 sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cart (cart_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_image BLOG, product_name TEXT, product_stall TEXT, product_price TEXT)");

 sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orderT (order_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_name TEXT, product_stall TEXT, product_price TEXT, product_stats TEXT)");
```

**insert ORDER method:**

```
 public void insertOrder(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("insert into orderT select cart_id, product_name, product_stall, product_price from cart");
    database.close();
}
```

**Error thrown:**

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 4 values for 5 columns (code 1): , while compiling: insert into orderT (order_id, product_name, product_stall, product_price, product_stats) select cart_id, product_name, product_stall, product_price from cart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set default value (for example, empty) for product_stats in your query:

```
database.execSQL("insert into orderT select cart_id, product_name, 
                  product_stall, product_price, '' as product_stats  
                  from cart");
```

Comment: what a quick resolved way! Never thought about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the column names in your statement as follows :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
    VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

By specifying the column names you can leave out the column you don't want to fill.